# Why is translate not working when I pass it as prop?

Tags: react-native, expo, i18next

Why it is not working ? I get no error...

```
## MEMO START ##
function isEqual(prev: IMyOrders, next: IMyOrders) {
  if(prev.name=== next.name) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const Item = ({
  name,
  t
}: { name: string; t: any; }) => {
  return (
    <Pressable style={s.item}>
       <Text style={s.product_name}>Ordered Date: { t('profile.logged.reviews.created_at', { date: order_date }) }</Text>
    </Pressable>
    )
  };

const MEMO_ITEM = memo(Item, isEqual);

## MEMO END ##

const SettingsMyOrders = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<IMyOrders> = ({ item }) => (
    <MEMO_ITEM 
      {...item}
      t={t}
    />
  );

  return (
     <FlashList 
       data={data}
       keyExtractor={(item, i) => item.name.toString()}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       estimatedItemSize={280.7}
     />
  )
}
```

Why it is not working when I put this with memo ? when leave the memo and dont put it as prop then works but thats not the way I want

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your custom are props equal function, because you have props as object. You can find more here -> https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/

Comment: The problem is if I have 100 items in list and I want to show a modal where I set the item ID in state then 100 items are rerenderd then its laggy. So with memo this does not happen it works fast

Comment: You should use memo, but with custom areEqual function :

function moviePropsAreEqual(prevMovie, nextMovie) {
  return prevMovie.title === nextMovie.title
    && prevMovie.releaseDate === nextMovie.releaseDate;
}
const MemoizedMovie2 = React.memo(Movie, moviePropsAreEqual);

Comment: I use it like this, look under Item , const MEMO_ITEM = memo(Item, isEqual);